# Query successful in phpMyAdmin can't be executed by my PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

The query is this one:

```
$query = 'SELECT X(`point`), Y(`point`) FROM `loc` INNER JOIN `user_loc` ' + 
         'ON `loc`.`id` = `user_loc`.`loc_id`;';
```

If I execute it using phpMyAdmin I have no problem, but in my PHP script I catch this error:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax

Where is the error? And why phpMyAdmin doesn't have any problem with it? I also used the "Validate SQL" tool in phpMyAdmin and there's no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the PHP. You concatenate strings with . not +:

```
$query = 'SELECT X(`point`), Y(`point`) FROM `loc` INNER JOIN `user_loc` ' . 
         'ON `loc`.`id` = `user_loc`.`loc_id`;';
```

Comment: ... and indeed `echo $query;` return `0`. I really hate PHP and all weak typing languages.

Comment: @Pinoniq: No? Do `echo 'hello' + 'world';` and `echo 5 + 'a';`

Comment: Whats the problem with that? It's not some strange behaviour

Comment: @Pinoniq: since the 'plus' operator is defined for numeric types and not for strings, if PHP was a strong typed language those operations will throw an error. But PHP is a weak typed language and it silently convert them to integers. PS: please add @ and my name without the space, or I'll not be informed about your reply.

Comment: @LucasMalor You are complaining that PHP doesn't know you actually want to concatenate string when you are using the wrong syntax? Like you said, 'plus' is a numeric operator, so don't use it for strings...

Comment: @LucasMalor what is the point of that wikipedia article? I know what weak typed and Strong types means. I'm simply pointing out that PHP has a different syntax then other languages. And that in PHP to concatenate string you have to use '.' instead of '+'.

Comment: @Pinoniq, I was replying to "This has nothing to do with weak typing". On the contrary PHP does an implicit conversion of string to integers in this case, and this is a weak typing behavior. I'm not complaining PHP can't concatenate strings with the plus operator. Implicit conversion is very useful in a language like PHP that operates a lot with strings, but an implicit conversion like this is not useful at all, since all the operands are strings and furthermore they are not numeric strings. I don't really see what such an implicit conversion can be used to, apart making debugging harder.